# C++ double colon in macro identifier

Tags: c++, macros, namespaces, c-preprocessor

I have a logging library for C++ projects that I use. It works in a namespace logger:: and inside that I have all necessary class definitions and pre-defined loggers;

```
namespace logger {

    class log_level {
        ...
    }

    log_level info;
    log_level debug;
}
```

Now, why is it logger instead of just log, well because C++ already has a log function, and this would cause a warning message:

```
warning: built-in function 'log' declared as non-function [-Wbuiltin-declaration-mismatch]
```

Now this is probably something that could be just ignored, **if** I don't use log function at all. But even then.. I don't like warnings and errors. So I came to think about a macro that would do the job..

But ever since trying, I have miserably failed as using double colon(:) in macro identifier seems to be a bit more difficult. Possibly impossible as well, but let's ask from the ones who might have better knowledge.

```
#define log::info logger::info
```

or

```
#define PREFIX_LOGGER_NS logger::
#define PREFIX_LOG_NS log::
#define log\:\:info PREFIX_LOGGER_NS info
#define log::debug logger::debug;
```

all fail.. So, is there a way out of this or is it too much to ask for a descriptive 3 word fake namespace? :)

---

I eventually decided to use namespace logger instead, even though I don't usually use **log** - it's better to keep that available and avoid unnecessary warnings.

Thank you for all answers given. They were all good :)

Comment: Can you quote something from the standard which implies that `:` can be part of any identifier? I cannot quote to the contrary now, but my first hunch is that it cannot.

Comment: Macro names do not take part in the namespace system, they all use the "global" namespace.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Not necessarily the fault of `using namespace std`, many implementations introduce names to the global namespace when you include `cmath`

Comment: @WeijunZhou hmm this warning is emitted (by gcc) even if you don't `#include <cmath>` at all.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI That means it's literally what the message says: It is a compiler intrinsic, which is just... too bad.

Comment: @WeijunZhou It is an intrinsic (kind of) but you cannot use it unless you declare it. The warning doesn't make much sense to me. OTOH if you do `#include <cmath>` you get a hard error.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I agree, maybe worth a bug report.

Comment: I would just pick a unique name, like `llog` and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible because macro substitution happens in translation phase 4, which works on the preprocessing tokens level. The tokens are formed in phase 3 under the rules detailed below. Double colon by itself is a preprocessing token. Quote from cppreference:

> 1. The source file is decomposed into comments, sequences of
>    whitespace characters (space, horizontal tab, new-line, vertical tab,
>    and form-feed), and preprocessing tokens, which are the following:
>
> a) header names such as  or "myfile.h"
>
> b) placeholder tokens produced by preprocessing import and module
> directives (i.e. import XXX; and module XXX;) (since C++20)
>
> c) identifiers
>
> d) preprocessing numbers
>
> e) character literals, including user-defined character
> literals(since C++11)
>
> f) string literals, including user-defined string literals(since
> C++11)
>
> g) operators and punctuators (including alternative tokens), such as
> +, <<=, <%, ##, or and
>
> h) individual non-whitespace characters that do not fit in any other
> category

Double colon falls into category g and cannot be combined with other characters to form a preprocessor token. That means from the perspective of a preprocessor, `log::info` cannot be treated as a whole at all. This is fundamental to the way how preprocessor works, and there is no possible way around it. If you attempt to somehow escape the colon, then a single colon itself becomes a single token and again cannot be combined with anything else (except maybe forming digraphs listed below). This is just as fundamental as there is no way to treat `a=` as a single token.

The complete list of operators and punctuators is given in [lex.operators](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.operators):

> ```
> #        ##       %:       %:%: 
> {        }        [        ]        (        )
> <:       :>       <%       %>       ;        :        ... 
> ?       ::       .        .*       ->       ->*      ~
> !        +        -        *        /        %        ^        &        |
> =        +=       -=       *=       /=       %=       ^=       &=       |=
> ==       !=       <        >        <=       >=       <=>      &&       ||
> <<       >>       <<=      >>=      ++       --       ,
> and      or       xor      not      bitand   bitor    compl
> and_eq   or_eq    xor_eq  not_eq
> ```

The `#define` preprocessor directive in addition requires the first token after `#define` to be a valid identifier.

For completeness, the requirement for an identifier is the follows,

> The first character of a valid identifier must be one of the
> following:
>
> - uppercase Latin letters A-Z
> - lowercase Latin letters a-z
> - underscore
> - any Unicode character with the Unicode property XID_Start

> Any other character of a valid identifier must be one of the following:
>
> - digits 0-9
> - uppercase Latin letters A-Z
> - lowercase Latin letters a-z
> - underscore
> - any Unicode character with the Unicode property XID_Continue

Answer (score 0):

As usual, MACRO is not the right tool for that.

We have [namespace alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias)

So you might use:

```
namespace log = logger;
```

And there are still `#pragma` to disable warning locally.

Comment: That won't work unless I leave cmath out. Even though I am not using cmath, idea is to re-use this "library", and it just might be that I end-up with a project that does use cmath. Anyway.. Without cmath.. namespace aliasing builds on gcc without warnings. And if cmath is included: error: 'namespace log = logger;' redeclared as different kind of entity - So this is not usable, unless you completely opt-out of cmath.